# WPF - How to give priority to the second element of DockPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, alignment, dockpanel

If have a `DockPanel` with two `Border` elements, first with `HorizontalAlignment="Left"` and second with `HorizontalAlignment="Right"`. The width of entire `DockPanel` is fixed but widthes of `Border`s should be changed depending to its content. Both borders have `TextBlocks`s. First `TextBlock` has word wrapping turned on the second is just one word. I want at first the second `Border` to be drawan and it should take all needed space and remaining space will be occupied by the first `Border` and it should use word wrapping to draw the content. This is my code which does not work because it first draws the first `Border` so no padding is left for the second one. Can you hint how to give priority to the second(right) element of `DockPanel`?

```
   <DockPanel>
   
        <Border Background="#FFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CornerRadius="4 0 0 4" Height="48" MaxWidth="183">
            <ContentControl VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Mode}" Value="trial">
                                <Setter Property="Content">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MaxWidth="190" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

                                            <TextBlock FontSize="12" TextWrapping="Wrap" Padding="11, 0, 11, 0">

                                            <Run Text="{Binding TrialText1, Mode=OneWay}"/>                                                   

                                            </TextBlock>

                                        </WrapPanel>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </Border>

        <Border CornerRadius="0 4 4 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MaxWidth="104" MinWidth="83">
            <Border.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFFF" Opacity="0.4"/>
            </Border.Background>

            <ContentControl VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Mode}" Value="trial">
                                <Setter Property="Content">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding PlanTitleText1}" FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                        </WrapPanel>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </Border>

    </DockPanel>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `DockPanel.Dock` attached properties while using `DockPanel`?

Comment: I added but it doesn't fix the width issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Grid instead. Define 2 Columns. Make the second one auto adjust how much space it needs and allow the first one to take all the remaining space.

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Border Grid.Column="0" (...)>
      (...)
   </Border>
   <Border Grid.Column="1" (...)>
      (...)
   </Border>
</Grid>
```